# Make Code more Responsive (Text over Image)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position, center

How would you create this but with percentages instead of pixels? Basically so no matter the size of image it is always centered both horizontally and vertically. Whenever I try to create with percentages, the dark background sticks completely out the side of the image.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/g13nn/pen/srpjG)

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
<div class="gallery-image">
  <img src="http://37.media.tumblr.com/bddaeb8fe12eda6bb40cf6a0a18d9efa/tumblr_n8zm8ndGiY1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg" width="300" height="200" />

<div class="gallery-text">

<h3>BOOM!</h3>

</div>    
</div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.gallery-image{
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.gallery-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
    transition: opacity 0.6s;
   vertical-align:middle;
   line-height:200px;
}

.gallery-text:hover{
    opacity: 1;      
}

.gallery-text h3{
    color: white;
    display: inline-table;
   vertical-align:middle;
   line-height:100%;            
}
```

Comment: Add wrapper div with `display: table` and inner wrapper with `display: table-cell` and other stuff just like image would be inside table.

Comment: Could you possibly post jsfiddle/codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this snippet, Hope this will help you!

```css
.gallery {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.gallery-image{
    position:relative;
    width:30%;
    height:30%;
    margin:10px;
}
.gallery-image1{
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
.gallery-image img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.gallery-image:after {
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.gallery-image:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
<div class="gallery-image">
  <img src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=8319683" />

<div class="gallery-text">

</div>    
</div>  
  
  <div class="gallery-image gallery-image1">
  <img src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=8319683" />

<div class="gallery-text">

</div>    
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: That's beautiful however there is no text?

Comment: Oh but you did that on purpose I think.

Comment: Ya the overlay is now responsive.. However, you can replace the content with whatever text you want!

Comment: Example? Place text under gallery-text? This is brilliant!

Comment: see content:'\A'; in css, Replace \A with some text!

Comment: Problem is I am using this in my index.php for blog posts the image links to the site and displays the title on the image when hovering. I can't use the_title(); in css :P

Comment: Are you loading the title dynamically?

Comment: Yes? I believe so. Based on the blog post title.

Comment: Then you've to pass the text using jQuery, If its a static content you just add the classes to the div and define the styles, Thats it!

Comment: That's behind the scope of my knowledge :P But thanks!

Comment: I figured out a completely different way to do it :P

Comment: You lead me on the right path though, I will leave this as the answer. I did not use js or jQuery.

Comment: Sounds great! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
```

on your `.gallery-text`-class :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #226699;
}

.img-holder {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
}

img {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" />  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Try using this css on your `.gallery-text` class.